# How to evaluate the derivative of a function defined by different formulas in different intervals?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function defined as following:
$f(x) = e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$ if $x \neq 0 ; f(0) = 0$

How should I proceed to evaluate it's derivative in $x= 0?$

Comment: Try to use the definition of derivative, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of derivative, we get

$
\begin{aligned}
f'(0) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}\\\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^\frac{-1}{h^2}}{h}\\\\
&= \lim_{x \to \pm\infty}\frac{x}{e^{x^2}}\\\\
&= 0
\end{aligned}$

where we make the substitution $x = 1/h$ in the second last step.